# Azure Databricks Light Runtime

Tags: azure-databricks

I am trying to create a Azure Databricks **Light** Runtime for some non-advanced performance. However, when creating a cluster, I was not able to find the specific runtime - (Databricks Light 2.4).

Can anyone share how to create a cluster with the expected runtime?

Many thanks!

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Azure Databricks Light Runtime is available only for jobs.

Databricks Light is the Databricks packaging of the open source Apache Spark runtime. It provides a runtime option for **jobs** that don’t need the advanced performance, reliability, or autoscaling benefits provided by Databricks Runtime.

Click on **Jobs** => **Create Job** => Click on **Edit** cluster details => Select **Databricks Runtime Version** => **Databricks Light** => **Light 2.4**

[image]

[image]

[image]

For more information, including instructions for creating a Databricks Light cluster, see [Databricks Light](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/runtime/light).